# Оптимальный вариант локальной именованной константы

Tags: c++, константа, локальные-переменные

Есть потенциально тяжелый (например, с необходимость динамического выделения памяти) локальный неизменяемый объект класса `BigObject`. Этот объект используется по месту, например:

```
void f() {
   g(BigObject{42});
}
```

Хочется этот `BigObject{42}` поименовать для улучшения самодокументируемости кода, например:

```
void f() {
   // static 
   // const
   // constexpr
   auto thing = BigObject{42};
   g(thing);
}
```

Можно ли предусмотреть вариант, подходящий в общем, или это всегда deal в зависимости от конечного использования?

Например, при однократном вызове `f` скорее всего достаточно иметь просто локальную константу, уничтожаемую при выходе из функции. Если вызовов много, то допустим `static`, чтобы не создавать объект N раз, но тогда он будет существовать до момента выгрузки кода, т.е. будет занимать память, когда уже перестал быть нужен.

Наверное, всё это ещё будет так или иначе обработано оптимизатором и реальный (низкоуровневый) код может быть совсем другим.

Тем не менее, какой вариант вам кажется предпочтительным и почему, какие плюсы и минусы вы видите для разных подходов, которые я не отразил в этом сообщении?

Comment: Оптимизировать до вызова профилировщика - впустую тратить время. Создавайте объект как можно ближе к месту использования (и по месту и по времени). Если в дальнейшем в профиле появится создание объекта - оптимизировать.

Comment: В вопросе на первом месте стоит прилагательное "Оптимальный", однако критериев оптимальности не задано. А вообще похоже, что вы на пути к изобретению синглетона.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вопрос скорее о том, что можно считать более общим случаем. Видимо, если нам более критична память - создаём non-static переменную. А если более критична производительность, то static вариант.